# JQuery change picture upon selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have list of options:

```
<li class="">
     <img src="/1.img" />
     <img src="/2.img" />
     Option 1
</li>
<li class="">
     <img src="/1.img" />
     <img src="/2.img" />
     Option 2
</li>
```

By default - 1.img visible. 
If user select for example Option 1, i want 1.img to hide(); and 2.img to show(); But just for Option 1. 
For example this code:

```
  $("#selection li").click(function(){
   $('.not-checked').hide(); // to hide image
   $('.checked').show(); // to show image
}
```

Change picture in every li. How can i change picture only on selected li ?

Comment: The answer you picked will change the picture only once. Consider my solution which will change pictures on every click, and is pretty short and elegant. @Rost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only target the children of the `<li>` element you're clicking on, you can make use of jQuery's **[`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** method. You want to find the `img` elements, and in order to target specific `<img>` elements, you can use the **[`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type)** pseudo-class:

```js
$("#selection li").click(function() {
  $(this).find('img:nth-of-type(1)').hide(); // to hide image
  $(this).find('img:nth-of-type(2)').show(); // to show image
});
```

```css
img:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selection">
  <li class="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50/ff00000/ff00000" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50/0000ff/0000ff" /> Option 1
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50/ff00000/ff00000" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50/0000ff/0000ff" /> Option 2
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply use a 'data-' attribute on all the elements and compare them in jquery.

```
<div id="selection">
<li class="" data-option="1">
    <img src="/1.img" data-option="1">
    <img src="/2.img" data-option="2">
    Option 1
</li>
<li class="" data-option="2">
    <img src="/1.img" data-option="1">
    <img src="/2.img" data-option="2">
    Option 2
</li>   </div>
```

And from your script

```
$("#selection li").click(function() {
    //first hide all images
    $(this).find("img").hide(); 
    //then show only the ones with the right data-option
    $(this).find("img[data-option="+$(this).data('option')+"]").show()
});
```

Btw, you do not always have to use data- it's just a jQuery convention of giving attributes to a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `toggle()` to achieve it.

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  $(this).find("img").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50/ff00000/ff00000" />
     <img style="display:none" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50/0000ff/0000ff" />
     Option 1
</li>
<li class="">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50/ff00000/ff00000" />
     <img style="display:none" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50/0000ff/0000ff" />

     Option 2
</li>
```

Explanation: `$(this)` will keep you in the clicked `<li>`; `find("img")` will target all of the images inside; `toggle()` will change the `display` for any targeted `img`;